# Java Inheritance Maximize reuse

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, code-reuse, extends

In following example, TreeNode is the superclass and BinaryNode is subclass.

```
public class TreeNode {
    private int data;
    private TreeNode parent;
    private List<TreeNode> children;

    TreeNode() {
        this.data = 0;
        this.parent = null;
        this.children = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    }
}
```

In subclass, every node has only two children. 
I write as following.

How should I write the member fields and constructor to best use the superclass, yet keep the structure right?

```
public class BinaryNode extends TreeNode {
//  int data;
//  BinaryNode parent;
    List<BinaryNode> children;

    BinaryNode() {
        super();
        children = new ArrayList<BinaryNode>(2);
    }
}
```

in constructor BinaryNode(), super() is called, what's the impact on children?

What's more, if the subclass has specific rules on some fields, like only two children in this sample, how to write the constructors in superclass and subclass to maximize reuse?

if I have the following method isLeaf() in superclass and don't write it in subclass. 
When I try to use it with a subclass instance, would it function correctly?

```
public boolean isLeaf() {
    if(this.children == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Just looking at this, is the point of this to make your own data structure?  If so then `children` should be lists or instances of the class you have i.e  `private BinaryNode leftNode;` and `private BinaryNode rightNode;`

Comment: There will be 2 "children" instances, one in the superclass, and one in the subclass... in the subclass, you cannot see the superclass' "children" field because it's private...

Comment: Answering the isLeaf() question: NO it will not work... just try it... the children field in the superclass is NOT the same as the one in the subclass. In your sub-class, you CANNOT see super's children... you need to make it protected, then get rid of children in the sub-class.... then your sub-class will have the "right" children :)

Answer (score 0):

You mark the attributes protected in the superclass and the subclass should have access to them:

```
public class TreeNode {
        protected int data;
        protected TreeNode parent;
        protected List<TreeNode> children;

    ...

    public boolean isLeaf() {
          if(this.children == null)
             return true;
          else
             return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what concerned me most is that do I have to rewrite the constructor altogether to get the two children feature or do I only need to rewrite the children part? can you give me an example?

Comment: `public class BinaryNode extends TreeNode {...}` - your child will still be this, but when you mark the parent class attributes as protected, the child class will then get access to them.